# Use WIQL to retrieve the results of a Team Query in TFS

Tags: tfs, wiql

Is there a way to retrieve the contents of a Team Query using WIQL?

Background: I'm throwing together an RSS feed for new bugs entered into TFS.  I could write a specific WIQL query for which work item types and states to include, but I'd rather just include the name of a team query - that way the team query name could be specified in the querystring of the RSS feed's URL, and you could use it to watch any set of work items.  Handy, right?  I'm just not sure whether WIQL can select items from a Team Query.  Anybody done that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to refer to or access a Team Query from within WIQL. The queries are stored in a separate subsystem in TFS that the query engine can't access.

Although it's not RSS, you might want to take a look at the [OData Service for Team Foundation Server 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/10/26/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-2010-v1.aspx).